# SSRS Parameter to select a column name on value which to filter the dataset

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, dynamic-sql

I need to allow my user to select a column name and its value from a parameter (or two params) to filter the result.

I have a text parameter with a few column names that are listed in my dataset
Column1, Column2, Column3.  Each of those columns has only two values 1 and 0.

I would love some help in getting an idea how to filter my dataset based on the column name listed in the parameter and a selected value (1 or 0)

I assume it has to be related to a dynamic sql but, not sure how to incorporate that in either the WHERE clause or the actual dataset filter.

Thanks for any points guys!! :)

Comment: How is your user accessing the report? Can you put some details about your architecture

Comment: Do you mean to show /hide the cols based on parameter or filter the rows based on the column.?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, guys :) 

Danish - My user is accessing a report from a ReportManager page.  

Mehra76 - I need to filter the rows based on the value of a column selected from a text parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the tablix you can use the filter section to set the criteria 
col1 = param1.This will only select the rows that match the value of the parameter.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2597/dataset-and-tablix-filtering-in-sql-server-reporting-services/

Comment: Sorry, no.  Perhaps I need to specify my question more precisely. 

I have a parameter with a list of column names from my dataset.  

That dataset has contains 
FirstName
LastName
Age
Column1
Column2

My parameter contains only column1 and Column2 values.   
I need to filter the dataset based on the values of a selected from a parameter column...does that makes sense? :)

Comment: @Tom,It is pretty simple .Let me know if you face any issues

Comment: so it is unknown which col needs to be filtered?

Comment: it is.  Col  will be picked by a user

Comment: thats fine , in the filter criteria set column1 = parameter1 and column2 = parameter2, if I understand correctly. You can also write an expression      Fields!Column1.value = parameter1

Comment: It's simple :) thanks!! :) 
but, I have 12 different column names in the drop down list of parameter1.  The dataset would need to be then filtered by the dynamically picked column name from the parameter1.  I'm sure I can set the column value (1,0) on another parameter but not sure how to determine filtering the dataset>
WHERE @ColumnName = 1 just doesn'

Comment: that is also doable .Go to Filter in the Tablix.In the expression "Fx" , open the window and create an expression like =IIF(Parameter1.Value ="Column1",IIF(Fields!Column1.Value = Parameter2.Value,True,False),IIF(Parameter1.Value="Column2",IIF(Fields.Column2.Value = Parameter2.Value,True,False)) Check the syntax and nested brackets as I do not have SSRS designer right now.

Comment: Thanks rmehra! (aaromba?).  I'll give it a go and see how I to work it! :)

Comment: Document maps are used in these type of scenarios rather than parameter dropdowns.            
     https://www.tutorialgateway.org/document-map-in-ssrs/

Comment: I've been looking into document maps but can't yet figure how to filter it all out. 
Its like to have a personal data with columns (plural not one column) for gender
Boy(1,0), Girl (1,0), TS (1,0), NS (1,0) and letting a user to select which gender they want to see

Comment: then the nested expression in the filter will be the best bet , even though it will be quite a lengthy expression

Comment: hmmm document map on a tablix level seems to be doing my trick :D Thanks rmehra!! :)